# webdriverio waitUntil and getUrl with pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver-io

In WebdriverIO I want wait until the browser is redirected to a URL that is having the word `project` in it. I tried to combine the `waitUntil` and `getUrl` functions but it is giving error message.

`TypeError: browser.getUrl(...).indexOf is not a function`

How can I build a condition to wait until the URL matching to a certain pattern?

Code:

```js
browser.waitUntil(() => {
  return browser.getUrl().indexOf('project') > -1
}, 5000)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`browser.getUrl()` returns a promise, which has no `indexOf` function. You need to save the result of `getUrl`, then run `indexOf` on that.

In sync mode:

```
browser.waitUntil(() => {
  let pageUrl = browser.getUrl();
  return pageUrl.indexOf('project') > -1
}, 5000)
```

In non-sync mode:

```
browser.waitUntil(() => {
  return browser.getUrl().then((pageUrl) => {
    return pageUrl.indexOf('project') > -1
  });
}, 5000)
```